# Which event triggers when the category page is loaded in magento2?

Tags: magento2, layout, category, event-observer

I need to apply condition based on the category filters applied to the layered navigation. Let me know which event name will help us to fetch the values to the observer file

Answer (score 1):

You can use the observer `catalog_product_collection_load_before`. You can see the example code inside the link. The example shows how to apply additional filter after a filter is applied.

Ref: [Magento Community Forum](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Problem-with-count-after-filtering-product/td-p/41485)

Comment: I need to trigger this event when the initial load of the category page using megamenu..which event is suitable for that?I am not able to achieve this using above.

Comment: Your question should be updated. The answer is totally different.

Comment: catalog_product_collection_load_before is removed in Magento v2.4.4